# Ektron dynamically adding FormFieldItem to FormBlock

Tags: ektron

I am working with and Ektron FormBlock and in my code behind I would like to dynamically add a FormFieldItem.  I have tried both the folliwng ways, but it always adds the items after the submit button.

```
FormBlock1.Controls.Add(myCntrl);
FormBlock1.Page.Form.Controls.Add(myCntrl);
```

What is the proper way to dynamically add a contorl to the form so it is in the formblock?  After inspection it looks like the controls property does not have the controls from the form.  There is also a Fields porperty but it is read only.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The formblock control will render the HTML for the form fields that are defined in the Workarea. It does not create ASP.NET controls for the form fields, it just creates HTML.

You could create your dynamic ASP.NET field some place else on the page. Then override your Page's Render method to move the HTML for your field into the HTML of the form block control.

When the page is submitted, the value in the dynamic field will not be saved into the Workarea by the FormBlock control. If you want to save some dynamic data, you can add a hidden field to the Form in the Workarea. When the user enters a value in your dynamic control, use JavaScript to copy the value to the hidden field.

Comment: Yes, got all that working. However, the control I want to add is a HTML input file upload.  My Ektron widget works great in a page, but not in a page builder page.  For some reason the request files collection is empty which leads me to believe the files are not captured on the submit.  Page build seems to be mucking with the form data somehow. Can you shed any light into that?

Comment: Widgets get built on update panels. That tends to muck with things. Some solutions are: If you are trying to do something on the jquery ready event, replace that with a call to ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript.
Also you may have to prevent the ajax behavior with ScriptManager.EnablePartialRendering  = false;